how to change font size in visual studio git copilot
I'm having trouble with the font size in Visual Studio Git Copilot. The text is very hard to read due to its small size. Could anyone provide guidance on how to change the font size in Git Copilot within Visual Studio? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
It is very hard to read:

whereas this text font size I can change:

but this part:

still has very small font and it is hard to read for me.

BTW I removed copilot because I found it very stupid. It just wasted my time. GPT chat much smarter and useful.
